# "An interview at the suggested [insert word here]" – time? moment? occasion? opportunity? juncture?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, time

I am looking for a word that means, *a particular date and time*. I need it to complete the following phrase:

*An interview at the suggested ____*

. *Time* is the most obvious, but it lacks the date component. 10AM is a time; 10AM this Tuesday is a... *juncture*. Since I'm not speaking to a fancy person, however, I worry that may come across as too formal. I don't think *moment* sounds right, as *10AM* in this context is likely an approximation, give or take about five minutes. Could *occasion* or *opportunity* be more appropriate? Perhaps.

Alternatively, there may be an adjective meaning, *as suggested*, which could complete the equivalent phrase:

*A ____ interview*

. Can anyone here help?

Comment: There is no single word that means both those things. How could there be?

Comment: 1) There are two questions here, really. For replacements for "suggested," please open a new question (actually, first use a thesaurus, then open a question only if that doesn't solve things). "Proposed" springs to mind. 2) Thank you for providing an example of how the word is used! It might be easier to understand the usage if it were a full sentence, though.

Comment: An interview at the suggested *time slot* of 10AM on Tuesday sets that as the time and date. People do not schedule interviews for any old 10AM, but for that time on a certain day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**10am on Tuesday is a time.**

Like many common English words, *time* has several meanings. It can mean "10am" or it can mean "10am on Tuesday 8th March 2022 CE". If someone says "I am free at 10am on Tuesday" and you say "I can do an interview at that time" the meaning will be completely clear to an English speaker. *"I can do an interview then" would also be unambiguous.

For your other suggestions, "moment" implies a very short period of time, "occasion" implies either an event or one of a sequence of events, and "opportunity" doesn't refer to a time at all.

For your second case, appropriate phrases might be:

> I can do an interview as suggested

> I can do an interview when you said

> I can do an interview then

Comment: Agreed, "time" is sufficient here. The question suggests that the word can only be used to mean *time of day* (i.e. clock time), which is not how it would be understood in this context.